# Data history value will remain after browser refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In my stop watch history table , it shows history of start time, end time, length, time between.
But if I refresh browser then previous value gone . I need previous data will remain for next time , data will store in local storage.

Thanks for any help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PadDigits(n, totalDigits)
        {
            n = n.toString();
            var pd = '';
            if (totalDigits > n.length)
            {
                for (i=0; i < (totalDigits-n.length); i++)


                {
                    pd += '0';
                }
            }
            return pd + n.toString();
        }

        var lastEndTime = null;
        var starttime = null;
        var endtime = null;

        function startTimer()
        {
            date = new Date();
            starttime = date;
            if(lastEndTime == null)
            {
                $('#history').html('');
            }
            $('#action').html('<img src="pause.png"><br>Stop Timer');
        }

        function stopTimer()
        {
            $('#action').html('<img src="play.png"><br>Start Timer');
            date = new Date();
            endtime = date;
            addRowToTable(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime);
            lastEndTime = endtime;
            endtime = null;
            starttime = null;
        }

        function addRowToTable(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime)
        {

            formattedStart = PadDigits(starttime.getHours(),2)+':'+PadDigits(starttime.getMinutes(),2)+":"+PadDigits(starttime.getSeconds(),2);
            formattedEnd = PadDigits(endtime.getHours(),2)+':'+PadDigits(endtime.getMinutes(),2)+":"+PadDigits(endtime.getSeconds(),2);

            seconds = parseInt((endtime.getTime() - starttime.getTime())/1000);

            lengthMinutes = parseInt(seconds/60);
            lengthSeconds = parseInt(seconds%60);
            lengthFormatted = PadDigits(lengthMinutes,2)+":"+PadDigits(lengthSeconds,2);

            if(lastEndTime == null)
            {
                timeBetweenFormatted = "N/A";
            }
            else
            {
                timeBetween = parseInt((starttime.getTime() - lastEndTime.getTime())/1000);
                timeBetweenMinutes = parseInt(timeBetween/60);
                timeBetweenSeconds = parseInt(timeBetween%60);
                timeBetweenFormatted = PadDigits(timeBetweenMinutes,2)+":"+PadDigits(timeBetweenSeconds,2);
            }



            $('#history').prepend('<tr><td>'+formattedStart+'</td><td>'+formattedEnd+'</td><td>'+lengthFormatted+'</td><td>'+timeBetweenFormatted+'</td></tr>')
        }

        function toggleTimer()
        {
            if (starttime == null)
            {
                startTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                stopTimer();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#action').click(function(kevent){
                toggleTimer();
            });

            $(document).keypress(function(kevent){
                $('#action').click();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body, body *{
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }
        body{
            margin:0px;
        }
        table.data-table
        {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 11px ;
            border: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-top: 1px solid #000000;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        table.data-table thead
        {
            border-top: 1px solid #000000;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        table.data-table thead th
        {
            background: #DDDDDD url(data-table-header.png) repeat-x top;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(248, 248, 248)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(248, 248, 248)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(233, 233, 233)), to(rgb(233, 233, 233))) content-box padding-box;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 2px;
        }
        table.data-table tr:nth-child(2n)
        {
            background-color: #ECF3FE;
        }
        table.data-table tr:odd
        {
            background-color: #ECF3FE;
        }
        table.data-table td
        {
            padding-left: 2px;
        }
        table.data-table tbody
        {
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        #action
        {
            border: 0px;
            background: transparent;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="action"><img src="play.png"><br>Start Timer</button><br>

    <div>
        <table class="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Length</th>
                    <th>Time Between</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="history">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems your question is unclear if you want to use local storage you can do localStorage.<key name> = value

Comment: Dive Into HTML5 has a great page on [how to use localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). You should start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to store all the previous values in a local storage you can store array of objects in to a local storage variable and than access it on page load.

The objective is to store the data into local storage once a lap is completed. And on browser refresh it has to check for stored laps, if any are stored it has to update them on html before proceeding. This will help you to achieve it.

```
var rows = new Array();

var lastEndTime = null;
var starttime = null;
var endtime = null;

function stopTimer()
{
    // Your code
    addRowToTable(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime);
    addRowToLocalStorage(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime);
}

// This will update your local storage data with all time laps
function addRowToLocalStorage(starttime, endtime, lastendtime)
{
    var row = {
        'startTime' : starttime,
        'endtime' : endtime,
        'lastendtime' : lastendtime
    };
    rows.push(row);
    localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify(rows));
}

// Onpage load, update all your local storage data to html
$(function(){
    var historyLaps = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData"));
    $.each(historyLaps, function(lap) {
        addRowToTable(lap.starttime, lap.endtime, lap.lastEndTime);
    });
});

// Deletes the local data. You can keep a rest button in html and tie it to this.
function clearStorage(){
    localStorage.removeItem('savedData');
}
```

This is untested code and probably might not work as expected. But, this will get you started. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookies which will be the easiest and simplest solution

check this

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp